# Adding a second Object to Collection VB

Tags: vba, distinct, reportbuilder3.0

I am working with a cube sourced dataset in PBI Report Builder.  Sum Distinct is not available in Report Builder so my work-around is a bit of custom code in the report.  The code below works perfectly but I need to add a second object 'Facility_Name' so that the collection evaluates on (Facility_Name, Budget).  I am stuck on how to accomplish this.  Help please.

```
Dim code1 As System.Collections.Hashtable

Function Bud(ByVal Budget As Object) As integer

dim flag as integer
        If (code1 Is Nothing) Then
             code1 = New System.Collections.Hashtable
        End If
        If (Not code1.Contains(Budget)) Then
                flag = 1
                code1.Add(Budget, nothing)
        else
                flag = 0 
        End If           
            Bud = flag 
End Function
```

Comment: Why do you try using .NET HashTable from VBA and not using native `Collection`? Or even better a `"Scripting.Dictionary"`. What kind of object is `Budget` you try using? Should the second parameter ('Facility_Name') be used as key to search for?

Comment: The script as is flags the unique objects "Budget', I need the script to flag the unique pairs of Facility_Name and Budget, essentially like a Group By .... Report Builder is very finicky and this script is something I found and was able to modify to get it to work

Comment: Shouldn't `Facility_Name` be unique?

Comment: I need the Flag = 1 on Budget where the combination of Facility_Name and Budget is unique.

Comment: So, `Facility_Name` shouldn't be unique? May the same string be used for more then one `Budget` objects? Can you give an example, since for me (at least) the `Budget` object is abstract?

Comment: Facility A 1134
Facility B 944
Facility C 421
Thanks for your help

Comment: But theses are not unique. I asked if **for the same facility it is possible to exist more `Budget` objects**... "May the same string be used for more then one Budget object?"

Comment: No, one facility - one budget | the problem is hat some facilities have the same budget and I need to sum the budget for all.  The report expression calls the function with an iif statement based on whether the flag = 1

Comment: So, a specific facility may be associated with a single budget. A step forward...  Now, in order to compare the objects, aren't they a specific distinct property to be used? A `Name` property, for instance. I asked for an example of such an object... What is it, in fact?

Comment: the Facility_Name is a string.  It is in reality a name

Comment: I did not ask about the Facility_Name, I asked about a 'Budget' object distinctive property to may compare them.  I must leave my office in about half an hour. So  I try being expeditive: Supposing that the objects have a distinct property, if this is checked and a match exists **what flag the code to use**? Should it be invented a new one (2)? Or what? I mean you cannot simple check `If Object1 = Object2`...

Comment: Facility_Name Budget flag
aaaaaa 112 1
bbbbbb 16 1
ccccccc 16 1
dddd 25 1
eeeee 30 1

Comment: I must confess that I cannot understand anything from your "clarification" answer... Please, try focusing on what I asked and if you have an answer to clarify the question, we can continue. Otherwise, it looks like we speak two different languages, even if both of us try English, no offence... I am not a English native speaker and it may be a reason, even if I do  not think so.

Comment: In the example I sent the collection would hold and flag 112, 16, 25, and 30 which sums to 183.  the function need to evaluate the Facility Name and Budget together so that the collection contains 112, 16, 16, 25, and 30 which sum to 199

Comment: I think none of programming languages is able to compare a string/object pair. But I cannot say I know all of them. VBA certainly cannot! So, if you cannot tell me anything about the secret object (`Budget`), one of its unique property to be used for comparison against another `Budget` object, I am afraid I cannot help... Does it have a distinctive 'name' property? I wish you a good day!

Comment: Before I leave, I would like to explain you how a `Dictionary` ('dict') works and what I had in mind asking about that property (preferable, returning a string): A `dict` keeps unique string keys. As values, you can imput everything, even an array containing objects, strings, doubles etc. I imagined a scenario to use `dict` key as the 'Budget' object string property and the object itself like the first element of an array. Then, **each time when a new `Facility_Name` are input for the same object, to be added in the 'dict' array**. In this way you can rapidly extract all facilities per object.

Comment: If the distinctive property will not be a string, the `Facility_Name` string will be used as key and then the object kept like value will be compared with the new one.

Comment: Your last comment is what might work - Thank you so much

Comment: But I hope you understood that two objects cannot be compared like `If Object1 = Object2`... That's why I was struggling to obtain from you an object property to  be used for comparison. I started asking myself if your object will not be an atomic bomb prototype... An what I tried suggesting in that comment can be better accomplished using a dictionary.